# Why Laravel still logging a NotFoundHttpException while all routes works?

Tags: nginx, routes, laravel, laravel-4

All my registered routes are working. They display the view, yet on every request a NotFoundHttpException shows up in my log file.

I'm using NGINX. Could it be my NGINX config?

The error that is logged on every request (even though the view shows up):

```
log.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /usr/share/nginx/www/example-staging/releases/20130815024541/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1429
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/nginx/www/example-staging/releases/20130815024541/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1050): Illuminate\Routing\Router->handleRoutingException(Object(Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException))
#1 /usr/share/nginx/www/example-staging/releases/20130815024541/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1014): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /usr/share/nginx/www/example-staging/releases/20130815024541/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(530): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /usr/share/nginx/www/example-staging/releases/20130815024541/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(506): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /usr/share/nginx/www/example-staging/releases/20130815024541/content/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#5 {main}
```

NGINX Config:

```
# Redirect www.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com/error.log;
    rewrite_log on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www/example/current/content;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~* \.php$ {
        # Server PHP config.
        fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index                   index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

        # Typical vars in here, nothing interesting.
        include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        # (deny .htaccess)
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be the `/favicon.ico`? Some web browsers request it even if not specified. What is the requested route as shown in the access.log?

Comment: Wow...you were right. It was the favicon. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This had nothing to with NGINX config.

The path to the favicon was incorrect. I assumed all resources were found because in the web inspector everything was status OK or 304. I guess the inspector doesn't show the favicon in the network tab.

As Rubens Mariuzzo mentioned, the access.log revealed that the favicon was status 500.

As a side note, if you would like Laravel to stop logging 404s/Resource Not Found as errors in log files, you can edit your `global.php` file like the following.

```php
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    // Don't log 404s
    if ($exception instanceof Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) {
        return;
    }

    Log::error($exception);
});
```

Comment: Inside of your nginx config, within the `server` block, consider adding: `location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }` and/or `location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }`